# Hosting site Asp.net MVC and SQL Server Compact 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, hosting, sql-server-ce, host

In my ISP, they must hire service SQL Server to host a  sql server compact framework?
The fact that MVC requires the host to have some extra service? Or a simple hosting plan already supports asp.net MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [bin-deploy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevelasker/archive/2008/10/22/privately-deploying-sql-server-compact-with-the-ado-net-entity-provider.aspx) SQL CE 4. Just make sure you are using the [RTM version](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=033cfb76-5382-44fb-bc7e-b3c8174832e2) because there was a problem with bin-deployment in betas. Also see [Scott Gu's blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/30/new-embedded-database-support-with-asp-net.aspx) about it.

ASP.NET MVC 3 can also be bin-deployed if your hosting provider doesn't have the assemblies installed in the GAC. All that's need is .NET 4.0.

This being said SQL CE is an embedded database and not designed to work in a heavy multithreaded environments such as ASP.NET. It is good for development and light-usage scenarios.  For high-volume sites and applications you'll probably want to migrate it to use SQL Server Express or SQL Server.

Comment: This will not be a tough environment.
I am opening a business will have almost no access at first. Once the company begins to grow, we will migrate to the Express