# How can I resolve my SQL Server CE error?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-ce

I need to my website users to be able to upload their `.sdf` files to my website.

Its working for me locally, but after I deploy to my hosting environment I get the following error:

> Unable to load the native components of SQL Server Compact corresponding to the ADO.NET provider of version 8482. Install the correct version of SQL Server Compact. Refer to KB article 974247 for more details.

My hosting account does not support SQL Server 4.0 Compact databases. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can bin-deploy SQL Server CE 4.0. See this Stackoverflow thread [Hosting site Asp.net MVC and SQL Server Compact 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398937/hosting-site-asp-net-mvc-and-sql-server-compact-4)